# What skills and specializations would make me a good candidate for Robotics field?

Tags: software-industry, career-switch, student

One year ago I graduated as a civil engineer and I don't like this field.

I decided to start studying from the beginning again in other university in one of these two fields **mechatronics engineering** or **computer science** but before taking any steps further I want to decide which is better suited if I'm interested in robotics, control systems and autonomous cars.

My wish is to work in a field related to these one day but I believe as a mechatronics engineer I won't find many job opportunities like the ones I find as a CS graduate

**My question is:** If I decided to study computer science and specialize in AI and deep learning will I be a good candidate to work in robotics field? - even if I had to study more topics as self-study?

Comment: Hey Antwan. I edited your post to make it more readable, better looking and more on-topic. Feel free to further edit it to fit your needs. Welcome to The Workplace :) I suggest you read [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to further improve the quality of the questions you post. Good luck with the career switch.

Comment: For the close-voters. This post was edited and is no longer asking for us to make a choice. Also, it is fairly focused and not "too broad" in my opinion (besides, it is highly answerable).

Comment: Are you sure that the correct answer is to complete a second undergraduate degree? It might be worth looking at MSc opportunities (or PhDs if you have great grades). An MSc would be faster to obtain, potentially holds more gravitas, and may go into more detail in the topics you are interested in.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to work with AI? Have you spent any time working with it? If not then it would be sensible to do so.... you don't want to spend the cash on a whole new career on a mere hunch that you might like it (you already did that with civil engineering!). Try before you buy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> before taking any steps further I want to decide which is better suited if I'm interested in robotics, control systems and autonomous cars.

I recall that, when I was at University (studied CS), my Mechatronic friends had several courses and topics regarding robotics, control systems, autonomous vehicles, etc. (in fact, those where the exact names of 3 courses they had), whereas I had other more software-oriented courses and topics.

If I where to chose between a CS and a Mechatronic student (assuming they are the same level of skill) for such job, *I'd say that the Mechatronic student is more likely to be a better fit.*

However, *this is not as simple and straightforward as it seems.* There could be a CS graduate that is better fit than a Mechatronic graduate, depending on the specific details and roles of the job.

> If I decided to study computer science and specialize in AI and deep learning will I be a good candidate to work in robotics field? - even if I had to study more topics as self-study?

Like I said, A Mechatronic graduate *could be* a better fit.

However, *AI is a really relevant topic for robotics, control systems and autonomous vehicles* (in fact, AI encompasses those and many other subtopics), so having a strong knowledge of AI would be a good thing for someone looking for such kind of jobs. A "pure" Mechatronic engineer could be lacking a bit on AI and Deep Learning knowledge compared to a CS engineer.

Finally, as a suggestion/opinion, **perhaps what you would like and what would be best for you would be to take the Mechatronic career, and complement it with elective courses on AI and related topics**, so you can have the "best of both worlds".

These are suggestions. As it is *your* career and *your* life, I suggest you take this into consideration along with any other input you have, and then take an informed decision. Good luck with the change.